# Facebook like button on a post not showing

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am working on a website and I am having problems with the like buttom of facebook
when someone do a post it should show the like button but I don't see it

I saw a similar question where one of the user said that if we use Facebook LINTER -> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint will fix the problem... But I still have the same error.

Here is what I got from the link

Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed

- Inferred Property:   The 'og:url' property should be explicitly
  provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

  Inferred Property:   The 'og:title' property should be explicitly
  provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

  Inferred Property:   The 'og:description' property should be explicitly
  provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

  Inferred Property:   The 'og:image' property should be explicitly
  provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

  Small og:image:  All the images referenced by og:image should be at
  least 200px in both dimensions.

Like Button Warnings That Should Be Fixed

- Admins And App ID Missing:   fb:admins and fb:app_id tags are missing.
  These tags are necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story
  that generates a high click-through rate.

  Like Button Tag Missing: og:title is missing. The og:title meta tag
  is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates
  a high click-through rate.

  Like Button Tag Missing: og:type is missing. The og:type meta tag is
  necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a
  high click-through rate.

  Like Button Tag Missing: og:image is missing. The og:image meta tag
  is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates
  a high click-through rate.

  Please check all the images with tag og:image in the given url and
  ensure that it meets the recommended specification.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: none of your og tags are being parsed for some reason.
if you can give us a link to your website it would be easier

Comment: here is the website http://dawgroup.net/pinrd/

Answer (score 1):

Look for JavaScript errors. If JavaScript gets broken on post, other elements like the Facebook like button will not render

Comment: ok the problem was on the JavaScript code like albatran said...now is working but for some reason only n my google chrome dont wrok every other website works perfect....also work on other computer as well eeven with google chrome